# subquery in where clause (mysql)

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

```
SELECT d.userID, (d.amountSuccessfulDeposits), (d.numberSuccessfulDeposits), cl.notes, d.asofdate, cl.send_date
FROM campaign_list cl
INNER JOIN deposit d
    on d.userid = cl.userid
WHERE cl.send_date > date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
    AND cl.send_date < date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND d.asofdate > date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
    AND d.asofdate < date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    and cl.notes in ('report11', 'report12', 'report13', 'report14', 'report15') 
    and d.asofdate > cl.send_date
```

After a userID enters a campaign (reports 11-15), the query calculates the number of deposits  made. "send_date" is the date that the userID is entered into the campaign. However, if a userID progressed further into another set of campaigns (reports 16-20), deposits made after entering the 2nd set of campaigns (16-20) shouldn't count towards 1st set of campaigns (11 - 15) query total.

***Example:***

Bob enters report 11 on 1/20

Bob deposits $100 on 1/21

Bob enters report 16 on 1/24

Bob deposits $500 on 1/25

**Therefore, the above query should only return $100 for Bob.**

```
userID;  amountSuccessfulDeposits; numberSuccessfulDeposits; notes;    asofdate;     send_date
2575192;   100.00;                       1;                 report11    ;2016-01-21    ; 2016-01-20
```

The following query didn't work

```
SELECT d.userID, (d.amountSuccessfulDeposits), (d.numberSuccessfulDeposits), cl.notes, d.asofdate, cl.send_date
FROM campaign_list cl
INNER JOIN deposit d
    on d.userid = cl.userid
WHERE cl.send_date > date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
    AND cl.send_date < date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND d.asofdate > date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
    AND d.asofdate < date(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    and cl.notes in ('report11', 'report12', 'report13', 'report14', 'report15') 
    and d.asofdate > cl.send_date 
    AND (   
                (SELECT (ocl.send_date) 
                    FROM campaign_list ocl
                    WHERE ocl.userID = cl.userID
                        and ocl.notes in ('report16', 'report17', 'report18', 'report19', 'report20')                   
                ) > d.asofdate
        )
```

Comment: Can we some sample table data and desired output?  Fastest way to get a quality answer here.

Comment: how do you enter numbers into a table? when I copy and paste from mysql client, it's a mess

Comment: Add four spaces in front of each line, which will force monospaced text.  So, just create a nice looking table in Notepad, add four spaces to the start of each line, and dump it into your question.

Comment: Ok. Please see my revision.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an inline view to get the "earliest" send_date for the follow on campaigns. (It's not clear if there is any relationship between the specific campaigns. If Bob enters any campaign 16-20, then the send_date of that campaign is the "cut off" for all previous campaigns 11-15)

Without a full understanding of the specification, I'm a little reluctant to suggest a query that will "work" for you.

But based on the given query, I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT d.userid
     , d.amountSuccessfulDeposits
     , d.numberSuccessfulDeposits
     , cl.notes
     , d.asofdate
     , cl.send_date
  FROM campaign_list cl
```

/* Here, I would create an inline view that gets the "earliest" `send_date` from the follow on campaigns 16-20, for each userid. And I do an outer join to that set, something like this */

```
  LEFT
  JOIN ( -- inline view to get earliest send_date
         SELECT ocl.userid
              , MIN(ocl.send_date) AS min_send_date
           FROM campaign_list ocl
          WHERE ocl.notes IN ('report16'
                             ,'report17'
                             ,'report18'
                             ,'report19'
                             ,'report20'
                             )
          GROUP BY ocl.userid
       ) oc
    ON oc.userid = cl.userid
```

/* With that, we will have the "earliest" `sent_date` from a follow on campaign associated. And that's now associated the row from the `cl` campaign. Now, we can do the join to the `deposit` table. My preference is to put *all* of the conditions on columns in `d` into the `ON` clause of the join, rather than the `WHERE` clause */

```
  JOIN deposit d
    ON d.userid     = cl.userid
   AND d.asofdate   > cl.send_date
   AND d.asofdate   > DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -7 DAY
   AND d.asofdate   < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -1 DAY
```

/* now here's the trick... */

```
   AND d.asofdate  <= IFNULL(oc.min_send_date,d.asofdate + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

including a condition that restricts rows from `deposit d` that have `asofdate` on or after the earliest `send_date` from a follow on campaign. The tricky part is that we need an OR condition, when there isn't a follow on campaign entery, the earliest `send_date` will be NULL.  If the value of `oc.min_send_date` isn't NULL, then we just use that. If it is NULL, we *substitute* a value that won't restrict the return of the row from `d`. A value greater than `d.asofdate` will work.

I'm using a `<=` (less than or equal to) test. If we just use a `<` test, it seems like a `deposit` with a `asofdate` that is on the *same* date as `send_date` will be a no man's land... it wouldn't be returned for the earlier campaign, because we already have a `>` (greater than) restriction `d.asofdate > cl.send_date`.

Then the `WHERE` clause with the restrictions on the rows from `cl` */

```
 WHERE cl.send_date > DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -7 DAY
   AND cl.send_date < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -1 DAY
   AND cl.notes    IN ('report11'
                      ,'report12'
                      ,'report13'
                      ,'report14'
                      ,'report15'
                      )
```

That's the approach I would take.

---

Or, **DEPENDENT SUBQUERY IN WHERE CLAUSE**

If there's some reason you *need* to include a dependent subquery in the `WHERE` clause...  you could write it as an `EXISTS` predicate... check whether there are any followon campaigns with send_date earlier than asofdate e.g.

```
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM campaign_list ocl
                    WHERE ocl.userID    = cl.userid
                      AND ocl.send_date < d.asofdate
                      AND ocl.notes    IN ('report16'
                                          ,'report17'
                                          ,'report18'
                                          ,'report19'
                                          ,'report20'
                                          )
                 )
```

Or, if there's some reason you need to do a scalar comparison of the return from the query (to do a less than/greater than comparison), then the return from the subquery *must* be a scalar... the query must return a single column and return (at most) one row.

To make sure no more than one row is returned, you can use an aggregate (e.g. `MIN()`, or you could use a `LIMIT` clause.  And you need to be ready to handle the NULL value that will be returned if no row is found.

```
 AND ( d.asofdate <= IFNULL( ( SELECT ocl.send_date 
                                 FROM campaign_list ocl
                                WHERE ocl.userID     = cl.userid
                                  AND ocl.send_date >= d.asofdate
                                  AND ocl.notes     IN ('report16'
                                                       ,'report17'
                                                       ,'report18'
                                                       ,'report19'
                                                       ,'report20'
                                                       )
                                ORDER BY ocl.send_date ASC
                                LIMIT 1
                             )
                     , d.asofdate
                     )
```

There might be some restrictions in MySQL, that dependent subquery might not be allowed in a `WHERE` clause. You could get it in a `HAVING` clause for sure. But the HAVING clause gets evaluated nearly last in the statement execution, after a GROUP BY operation.